# Get the height of a same domain iframe when that iframe is inside a different domain iframe?

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, cross-domain, same-origin-policy

I have a site which has a media player embedded inside an iframe.  The media player and the site are on the same domain, preventing cross-origin issues.  Each page, the main page as well as the media player page, have a bit of code which finds the height and width of any parent iframe:

```
var height = $(parent.window).height();
var width = $(parent.window).width();
```

No problems so far....until:

A client wants to embed my site inside an iframe on his own site.  His site is on a different domain.  Now, my iframe is inside another iframe and my code is throwing cross-origin errors.

The following does not throw errors:

```
var test1 = parent.window; // returns my site
var test2 = window.top;  // returns client site
```

The following does throw cross-origin errors:

```
var test3 = parent.window.document;
var test4 = $(parent.window);
var test5 = window.top.document;
var test6 = $(window.top);
```

How do I get the height of the iframe on my domain without the cross-origin errors?  I'm hoping for a pure javascript/jQuery solution.

Options which will not work for my solution are:

1. Using document.domain to white list the site.
2. Modifying the web.config to white list the site.

Like in Inception, I must go deeper.  Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is running from the iframe in the middle of the parent and the child window.  So, anytime you call

```
window.parent
```

and your site is embedded inside an iframe and the parent is a different domain (Same origin policy), an error will be thrown.  I would recommend first checking if the parent is the same origin.  You need to wrap this check in a try catch.

NOTE:  Most browsers, but not Edge, will not throw an error if the parent is http://localhost:xxx and the iframe is http://localhost:zzz where xxx is a different port number than zzz.  So, you also need to manually check the origins match by comparing the protocol, domain, and port.

```
var isEmbeddedInCrossOriginIframe = false;
try {
  var originSelf = (window.self.location.protocol + '//' + 
                    window.self.location.hostname + 
                   (window.self.location.port ? ':' + 
                    window.self.location.port : '')).toLowerCase();
  var originParentOrSelf = (window.parent.location.protocol + '//' + 
                    window.parent.location.hostname + 
                   (window.parent.location.port ? ':' + 
                    window.parent.location.port : '')).toLowerCase();
  isEmbeddedInCrossOriginIframe = originSelf != originParentOrSelf;
}
catch(err) {
  isEmbeddedInCrossOriginIframe = true;
  //console.log(err);
}
```

Your solution will then be:

```
var height = $(isEmbeddedInCrossOriginIframe ? window : parent.window)
             .height();
var width = $(isEmbeddedInCrossOriginIframe ? window : parent.window)
            .width();
```

Answer (score 1):

You will need to use [Javascript's messager](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MessageEvent). First, you need to define a `function` like this:

```
function myReceiver(event) {
    //Do something
}
```

Then you need an event listener:

```
window.addEventListener("message", myReceiver);
```

You will need something like this on both sides. Now, you can send a message like this to the `iframe`:

```
innerWindow.contentWindow.postMessage({ message: {ResponseKey: "your response key", info1: "something1", info2: "something2"}}, innerWindow.src)
```

and this is how you can send a message to the parent:

```
window.parent.postMessage({ message: {ResponseKey: "your response key", info1: "something1", info2: "something2"}}, myorigin);
```

The only missing item in the puzzle is `myorigin`. You will be able to find it out in your `iframe` using `event.origin || event.originalEvent.origin` in the message receiver event.

However, the pages using your site in their pages inside an `iframe` will have to include a Javascript library which will handle the communication you need. I know how painful is this research, I have spent days when I have done it before to find out the answer.

Comment: i like the idea of using this to invert control.  When my parent page has a page resize() event, it can message the child iframe page with new dimensions.